# Is this really a dependent template name?

Tags: templates, gcc, clang, c++17, language-lawyer

I have some code that fails to compile, which I reduced to the following minimum version:

```cpp
class Builder
{
    public:
        Builder()
        {}

        auto foo(int) -> Builder &
        {
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T>
        auto bar() -> Builder &
        {
            return *this;
        }
};

template<typename T>
Builder get_builder()
{
    return Builder().foo(T()).bar<T>();
}

int main()
{
    auto builder = get_builder<int>();
    (void) builder;
}
```

[See on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bq6WERyOU9XMlpWN)

Clang (9.0.0) rejects this with:

```
prog.cc:22:31: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'bar' as a dependent template name
    return Builder().foo(T()).bar<T>();
                              ^
                              template
```

Is Clang right saying that `bar` is a dependent template name? VS 2017 sees no problem. GCC (9.2.0) also rejects the code, but with a much more obscure error message:

```
prog.cc: In function 'Builder get_builder()':
prog.cc:22:36: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   22 |     return Builder().foo(T()).bar<T>();
      |                                    ^
prog.cc:22:38: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   22 |     return Builder().foo(T()).bar<T>();
      |
```

Changing the offending line as Clang suggests

```cpp
return Builder().foo(T()).template bar<T>();
```

fixes compilation for Clang and GCC. VS2017 also accepts this version.

**It seems the solution is simple**, but if I reorder the function calls:

```cpp
return Builder().bar<T>().foo(T());
```

or remove the parameter from `foo`:

```cpp
return Builder().foo().bar<T>();
```

the error is gone.

What is going on here?

1. Are Clang and GCC right rejecting the original version?
2. Are Clang and GCC right accepting the changed versions (reordered, changed `foo`)?
   If so, why? What is the difference?

Comment: My guess here is that since you pass `T` to `foo`, the compiler will not try to figure out which overload of `foo` to call, but instead just treat it as a dependent name. In this case there is only one overload, so from the human perspective it can seem obvious but it's easy to imagine a scenario with several `foo` overloads with different return types.

Comment: In that  case, why does reordering of function calls fix the problem?

Comment: Since `Builder()` is not dependent. You use `template bar` not because `bar` is dependent, but because `foo` is dependent.

Comment: Or maybe more accurately phrased as *the return value from `foo`* is considered dependent.

Comment: ...and if `foo` does not take a `T()` parameter, its return value is no longer dependent? It all seems very convoluted and unclear for me.

Comment: If `foo` does not take a dependent parameter the compiler would know which overload is being called, thus it would know what the return value is. If it doesn't, it doesn't. Seems very logical to me.

Comment: You don't find it strange that MSVC allows [this](https://godbolt.org/z/_Khnqu)?

Comment: @super, thanks for mentioning it, I was just about to comment the same! (Well, not quite the same: GCC/CLANG reject even the simplest case of this, which MSVC handles just fine -- not according to the std., but according to common sense.) This reminds me of the old template `stuff<X<Y>>` days, where we were forced to put a space between the '>'s to avoid an ambiguity. That one took a decade or so to heal, so this may not get fixed in my lifetime then. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, MSVC (incorrectly) allows code that requires the `template` keyword (even with `/permissive-` defined).

The code in question *does* require `template` to disambiguate that `bar` is a template name. gcc and clang are correct in diagnosing this. It is possible that an overload of `foo` is present that returns a different type depending on `T`. Therefore the call to `bar` depends on the template parameter.

Consider the following:

```
struct FooBar
{
   template<class T>
   auto bar() -> T
   {
       return 42;
   }
};

class Builder
{
    public:
        Builder()
        {}

        auto foo(int) -> Builder &
        {
            return *this;
        }

        auto foo(short) -> FooBar
        {
            return {};
        }

        template<typename T>
        auto bar() -> Builder &
        {
            return *this;
        }
};
```

called with:

```
auto builder = get_builder<short>();
```

The **possibility** of an overload (not the actual presence) makes the name dependent. Refer to [[temp.dep]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep) (*emphasis* mine):

> Inside a template, some constructs have semantics which *may* differ from one instantiation to another. Such a construct depends on the template parameters.

The compiler is not obligated to check all instantiations of the template to see if there is only one possible function in the overload set.

Comment: In your example, there **is** an overload of `foo` that returns something else. In my example, `foo` **is not** overloaded. How can you then say that *an overload of `foo` may be present*? Is it just because `foo` takes a parameter, it *could* potentially be overloaded, so `bar` **is** dependent?

Comment: The possibility of an overload makes it dependent, not the actual presence